# AVR programming, displaying wrong value on 7 seg. LED

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega

I am interfacing LM35 with Atmega8. To display digits I use 7 segment LED anode display that I connect to AVR both ends (it handles it without transistors so why not). Strange thing happens:
res value after assigning it from adc is 237 (23.7 degrees). I want to print on my display the first digit (2).
If I leave last line in the while commented out, the display first shows digit 2 correctly but after the first delay it shows 1 instead of 2. Otherwise I get correctly digit 2. Why is this happening?

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#endif // F_CPU

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define DELAY_IN_MS 500 /* 0.5 sec */

int numbers[] = {
    0b01000000,
    0b01110011,
    0b00100100,
    0b00100001,
    0b00010011,
    0b00001001,
    0b00001000,
    0b01100011,
    0b00000000,
    0b00000001,
    0b11111111 // off
};

uint8_t digits[3];

void initADC()
{
    ADMUX=(1<<REFS1)|(1<<REFS0);
    ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0);
}

uint16_t ReadADC(uint8_t ch)
{
    //Select ADC Channel ch must be 0-7
    ch=ch&0b00000111;
    ADMUX|=ch;

    //Start Single conversion

    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);

    //Wait for conversion to complete
    while(!(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)));

    //Clear ADIF by writing one to it
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);

    return(ADC);
}

int main()
{
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    PORTD = 0xFF;

    DDRB = 0b00000001;
    PORTB = 1;

    initADC();

    uint16_t adc_value;
    uint16_t res;
    while(1)
    {
        adc_value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            adc_value += ReadADC(0);
        }

        adc_value=(adc_value/25)/4;
        res = adc_value;

        for(int j = 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            digits[j] = res%10;
            res /= 10;
        }

        uint8_t dig = digits[0];
        PORTD = numbers[dig];
        _delay_ms(DELAY_IN_MS);

        // if following is uncommented there blinks digit two correctly
        // if commented there is unblinking digit 1 
        PORTD = numbers[10]; // display off
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmmm might be wrong array index or MSB or LSB first situation?

Comment: Not sure what's the problem, but i would change the numbers array to be `uint8_t` instead of `int`. Do you have any possiblity to debug your code?

Comment: @Maku ok. Sadly i cant debug it (or dont know how). the only thing I can "debug" is LM35 output, which i can read with voltmeter. I wonder, is it possible that the display is draining too much so the ADC is not calculating correctly?

Comment: The resolution of the given ADC is kind of important here. Unless it is 8 bits, this code will crash and burn, since you cannot store the sum of 250 ADC reads in a 16 bit variable.

Industry minimum standard for microcontrollers is 10 bit ADC. 12 bit is increasingly common. Are you actually using an 8 bit ADC?

Comment: @Lundin why should it "crash and burn"? It's true that 250*16bit won't fit inside a 16bit variable, but it won't crash - it will just roll over if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Maku Depends on the size of `int` but I'm guessing it will be 16 bits here, so indeed there will just be an unsigned wrap-around in that case. At any rate this code probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lundin I have 10-bit ADC, but 16 bit is enough, because if i measured e.g. 30 degrees the value in the variable would be 30*4*250 = 30000 = 0111 0101 0011 0000 which fits into 16 bits perfectly. I am measuring room temperature which hardly exceeds 65 degrees celsius (16 ones).

Comment: An ADC returns raw number, not "degrees" or any other unit. It is a value 0 to 1023 that corresponds linearly to the voltage 0V to Vref, nothing else. You cannot assume that your input will always be correct, your program cannot be allowed to run haywire if it doesn't. At a minimum, add some error handling.

Comment: With your explanation that you think you are getting scaled degrees in Celsius from the ADC, the question no longer makes any sense. I have no idea what you are doing. Provide a schematic and post it on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Lundin why would it make no sense. I have posed clear question, with readable code. If you don't know the answer than why do you answer. If you need more details read please this tutorial which I followed http://extremeelectronics.co.in/avr-tutorials/interfacing-temperature-sensor-lm35/ you will understand how the conversion of LM output works. The difference is that I do not use VRef (5V) but only internal 2.56V. And of course I wrote my own code to be sure it fits my atmega.

Comment: A comment is not an answer. I post a comment since I don't understand the question. By Vref I mean the ADC reference - the supply is typically called Vdd or such. Anyway, the method used for scaling does not matter, because that is applied _after_ you sum the ADC reads. The fact remains that `1023 * 250` does not fit in a 16 bit variable. Neither does 250 values with an average of less than a third of the ADC value range, `333 * 250`.

Comment: @Lundin ok I get your point, I change it to 32bit, the problem persists anyway. As I said in comment above, when the display is off, the resulting value is correct, when it is on during the adc calculation, it gives wrong value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was induction.

My circuit had many wires in non-soldering-field. When the display was on, there was a lot of induction going on changing resulting voltage on ADC input/LM35 output.
There is more than one solution.

1) Software: I moved ADC conversion into the interruption function. It turns of the displays, converts value from lm35 and displays digit on proper display. It happens so fast that the eye cant perceive it. 
I prefer this one for now, because it makes my circuit simpler.

2) Hardware: adding L/C or R/C filter to adc pin should resolve the issue.

Full code for 1)

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#endif // F_CPU

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define DELAY_IN_MS 5000 /* ms */
#define NUM_OF_MEASUREMENTS 100
#define NUM_DISPLAYS 3

int numbers[] = {
    0b10000001,
    0b10011111,
    0b10100100,
    0b10010100,
    0b10011010,
    0b11010000,
    0b11000000,
    0b10011101,
    0b10000000,
    0b10010000,
    0b11111111 // off
};

int display = 0;
uint8_t digits[NUM_DISPLAYS];
volatile uint16_t adc_values[NUM_OF_MEASUREMENTS];
int adc_read_cycle_index = 0;
uint32_t res;

void initADC()
{
    ADMUX=(1<<REFS1)|(1<<REFS0);
    ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2);
}

uint16_t ReadADC(uint8_t ch)
{
    //Select ADC Channel ch must be 0-7
    ch=ch&0b00000111;
    ADMUX|=ch;

    //Start Single conversion
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);

    //Wait for conversion to complete
    while (ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC));

    return(ADC);
}

void readDegrees()
{
    adc_values[adc_read_cycle_index] = (ReadADC(0)*10)/4;

    if(adc_read_cycle_index + 1 == NUM_OF_MEASUREMENTS) {
        adc_read_cycle_index = 0;
    } else {
        adc_read_cycle_index++;
    }
}

void fetchTemperatureDigits() {
    res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MEASUREMENTS; i++) {
        res += adc_values[i];
    }
    res /= NUM_OF_MEASUREMENTS;

    for(int j = 2; j >= 0; j--) {
        digits[j] = res%10;
        res = res / 10;
    }
}

void initTimer0()
{
      // Prescaler = FCPU/64
      TCCR0|=(1<<CS01);//|(1<<CS00);

      //Enable Overflow Interrupt Enable
      TIMSK|=(1<<TOIE0);

      //Initialize Counter
      TCNT0=0;
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    // turn off displays
    PORTD = numbers[10];

    // read ADC and convert to degrees
    readDegrees();

    // turn on proper anode
    PORTB &= 0b11111000;
    PORTB |= (1<<display);

    // show digit
    PORTD = numbers[digits[display]];
    // show decimal point for second display (21.5 - second display shows "1.")
    if(display == 1) {
        PORTD &= 0b01111111;
    }
    // next display for next interruption
    display++;
    if(display == NUM_DISPLAYS) {
        display = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    initADC();
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MEASUREMENTS; i++) {
        readDegrees();
    }

    DDRD = 0xFF;
    PORTD = 0;

    DDRB |= 0b00000111;
    PORTB |= 1;

    initTimer0();

    sei();

    while(1) {
        fetchTemperatureDigits();
        _delay_ms(DELAY_IN_MS);
    }

    return 0;
}
```